# Vanishing Gradient in Keras Spelling Correction Model

Tags: keras, nlp, tf.keras

I'd like some help with the following problem.

I'm working on a spelling correction model using Tensorflow (Keras). I'm using "binary accuracy" and "accuracy" as my metrics. Consistently, the model's loss starts at 0.6831 and the accuracy starts at 0.000. The value of the loss decreases gradually but as soon as the accuracy gets a value higher than 0.000, the loss becomes "nan". This happens at about the 6th step of the first epoch. My loss function is BinaryCrossEntropy.

```
#model definition

input_layer = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1]),name='input_layer')
sp_embedding_layer = Embedding(len(char2idx),EMBEDDING_DIM)(input_layer)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(512,return_sequences = False,activation = 'relu'))(sp_embedding_layer)
x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_1')(x)
x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_2')(x)
x = Dense(y_train.shape[1],name='Output',activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
model = models.Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = x)

# Optimizer
myoptimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001,clipnorm = 0.1)
model.compile(optimizer=myoptimizer,loss=safe_binary_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy',keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])


def safe_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 0), tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon()), y_pred)
    y_pred = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1), tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon()), y_pred)
    return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_val,y_val),epochs=10,callbacks=callbacks_list,batch_size=32)
```

I found a custom loss function which I've incorporated (shown in the code as "safe_binary_crossentropy"). It's been incorporated but the behaviour is still the same. I was hoping to have the loss value as numeric and reducing gradually.

My data is one hot encoded and the correction is at character level. My vocab size is 53. The model input and output size is 2650. I set the clipnorm parameter as well but still nothing works. I'll appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Some suggestions:  Try reducing the learning rate. Add `BatchNormalization` before and after each hidden layer's activation function. Use weight initialization: for `relu` activation functions use `kernel_initializer="he_normal"`. Try changing your activation functions to: `elu` or `selu` and keep the He weight initialization. Finally, you can apply gradient clipping.